# Changing the WHAT column of DBA_JOBS

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, materialized-view

I am using a job to update a materialized view.

I found that the job would lock itself if the `exec dbms_refresh.refresh(''"<schema>"."<materialized_view_name>"'');` was not committed and I would like to change the "what" column of the job to include a commit.

I face two possible solutions :

solution 1: a more complicated way is to recreate the job entirely, which I would like to avoid

Run `SYS.DBMS_JOB.REMOVE(14133); COMMIT;`

Recreate the whole job to now include the commit

```
DECLARE
  X NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SYS.DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT
  ( job       => X 
   ,what      => 'exec dbms_refresh.refresh(''"<schema>"."<materialized_view_name>"'');COMMIT;'
   ,next_date => to_date('11-11-2016 00:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
   ,interval  => 'trunc(sysdate)+1   '
   ,no_parse  => FALSE
  );
  SYS.DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Job Number is: ' || to_char(x));
COMMIT;
END;
/
```

solution 2: update the DBA_JOBS view directly by running a normal update statement on the view

```
update dba_jobs set what=(
select what from dba_jobs 
where job in ( '1','2','3','<etc>')
)||'COMMIT;'  
where job in ( '1','2','3','<etc>');
```

Is there a better solution than these two, is solution two possible ?

I'd like to avoid solution 1 as let's imply I don't have the code for the view at hand it would take more time plus let's imply I have hundreds to modify.

Comment: Trying to change the way the job is executed

Comment: NEVER try to update the dba_ or v$ views...  in addition: dbms_scheduler replaced dbms_job in 11g, so I would recommend switching to dbms_scheduler anyways.  Also, since the mview is already in a refresh group, why can't you just set the refresh interval from that interface instead of needing to refresh via dbms_job anyways (unless you need some odd refresh schedule that isn't supported through dbms_refresh (but that doesn't appear to be the case here since you are just refreshing once a day).  dbms_scheduler jobs can be modified using: exec dbms_scheduler.set_attribute.

Comment: Solution 1 is more appropriate. Don't do solution 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Really? `DBMS_JOB` has a procedure called `CHANGE`.

```
declare
  jobno number;
begin
  dbms_job.submit(jobno, 'begin null; end;');
end;
/
commit;

select job, what from user_jobs;

       JOB WHAT                         
---------- ------------------------------
         1 begin null; end;    

begin
  dbms_job.change(1, 'begin null; commit; end;', null, null);
end;
/
commit;

select job, what from user_jobs;

       JOB WHAT                         
---------- ------------------------------
         1 begin null; commit; end;
```

Comment: Oh, it was THAT easy. Off to write a query-generating query to batch these with dbms_job.change thanks balazs